# Excel vb error : Compile error invalid use of property

Tags: vba, excel

I have an accounting system that creates a report from SQL database, it puts the report data on sheet1(Report) and report paramters on sheet 2.
i need to sort the data and hide a few columns when the accounting system has complted the dump

on sheet1 i put the following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Sort
HideExtraFields
End Sub
```

in module1

```
 Sub Sort()
 Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
    ("E2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
    ("D2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub

 Sub HideExtraFields()

Columns("AA:AE").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

if i move the code on sheet1 to ThisWorkbook, i get error for it is still dumping paramters on sheet2

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Sort
HideExtraFields

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line has the error ?

Comment: on sheet1 the line with sort

Comment: Your column header labels seem to be in row 2; what is in A1 and what is the extents (i.e. range) of the data to be sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just sorting, `AutoFilter` is not needed for sorting; drop it and drop the use of the hazardous `Selection` stuff. Try it this way.

Preferably, I will put all in the code module of the worksheet Report

```
' Code Module of the worksheet Report
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  SortMe
  HideExtraFields
End Sub

Sub SortMe()
  With Me.Sort.SortFields
    .Clear
    .Add Key:=Me.Range("E2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
    .Add Key:=Me.Range("D2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
  End With

  With Me.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .SetRange Me.UsedRange
    .Apply
  End With
End Sub

Sub HideExtraFields()
  Me.Columns("AA:AE").Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @Tinashe I modified it to put all that code in the module worksheet Report. I prefer you try it this way, it's cleaner.

Comment: @ A.S.H tx for quick response, with this option i am getting error member aalready exists in an object module from which this object module derives, from the first option it was sorting but it did not hide the columns

Comment: @Tinashe yeah, I see, it's because of the name of the `Sort` routine. We only need to change the name, I changed to `SortMe`. Please try the edited version.